# how to reflect changes in a calling activity in android?

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I have a list view containing names.I am able to add those names to phones's contact list but the changes are not getting reflected in my list view untill I restart the application again.kindly help.thanks in advance.
I have tried this but ain't working.

```
public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repopulate your listview in onResume() of your activity,so that changes will appear in your listview after you will add new data.

```
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        populateListview();
}

public void populateListview()
{
    //reset adapter
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: what I have just  come across is a strange thing that even the device is not updating its callog.calls table until it is not opened manually.may be that is why I am not getting the updated values in my list view because callog.calls is the source from where I am retrieving dialed numbers an their names.any suggestion how I can refresh that.

Comment: i have never come across such problem.Its really strange!  are you sure,you haven't got problem with your AVD,assuming you are testing on AVD and not the real device!?

Comment: I think I have to update callog.call.cached_name manually.I  think it will work but don't know how to update.any help in this matter would be appreciable.I am quite sure it is going to work but I am quite new to sql lite database.by the way thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in this case is whenever you add the list item you need to set the `Adapter` again. or you can call the `notifyDatasetchanged()` method.

Comment: it is not working for me,by the way where I have to add this method.I am adding it after listview.setadapter(adapter).

Comment: better you use SetAdapter only while adding the item. it will work for  sure

Comment: lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  lvar = new ListViewAdapterRecent(this, names, types, duration,uniqueid,numb);
  lv.setAdapter(lvar);

  lvar.notifyDataSetChanged();//this is what I am using.I think I am using setAdapter once only.am I wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this.Hope this will solve your problem.

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);        
}
```

Or

```
   //lv is your ListView
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   lv.invalidateViews();
```

after the contact list is updated.